# how to hide/show multiple user interface controls, in a Visual Basic 2013 ASP.NET web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

As a user steps through my web page, I want to be able to show a group of controls,
then when user is done with those, I want to hide them, and then show a 2nd group...then a 3rd, etc.

Is the Toolbox > Panel the only way to hide/show?
Or are there alternatives?

Web needs to work on the widest variety of browsers.

Comment: Client side or server side?

Comment: Panel, PlaceHolder, CustomControls, and any control that can contains other controls (like the wizard) can probably fit you.

Comment: You could even hide each individual control if you liked. Panel renders as a div and is probably as easy as any other to show / hide server side. Client side, I'd go with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Panel control in the toolbox, and then controlled its .visual property.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery on the client side

You can place the control groups into divs with css classes ("Section1Hidden", "Section2Hidden").

You can then use JQuery to replace the css classes as you step through your application ("Section1Display", "Section2Display").

The css for Section1Hidden (display:none).

The css for Section1Display will not have display:none.